# `const` type parameters fail on Typescript 5.3 for mutable array constraints

Tags: typescript

My understanding of [microsoft/TypeScript#55229](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/55229) is that it dropped the requirement of using the `readonly` array modifier for const type parameter inference.

However, in the following three examples, the `readonly` modifier is still required for const inference to work. Each of the three examples includes a workaround or modification that can be made to "enable" const inference that does not include adding `readonly` to `Foo` or `Bar`. Confusingly, the fourth example actually works as is despite it being similar to the third.

```
type Foo = {
  foos: string[]; // adding readonly here makes the original cases work
};
type Bar = {
  bars: number[]; // adding readonly here makes the original cases work
};
type Mapped<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};
type MappedWorkaround<T> = T extends T ? Mapped<T> : never;

// For example, try changing the below to `const Item extends MappedWorkaround<Type extends 'Foo' ? Foo : Bar>`. It will work.
//  (Or, add a readonly modifier to Foo.foos and Bar.bars.)
const fn1 = <Type extends 'Foo' | 'Bar', const Item extends Mapped<Type extends 'Foo' ? Foo : Bar>>(params: { Type: Type, Item: Item }) => params.Item;
const test1 = fn1({
    Type: 'Foo',
    Item: {
      foos: ["huh"]
    }
  });

// This has the same "depth" as the object case above, except it uses a tuple instead of an object
//  The workarounds for fn1 apply here as well.
const fn2 = <Type extends 'Foo' | 'Bar', const Item extends Mapped<Type extends 'Foo' ? Foo : Bar>>(params: [Type: Type, Item: Item]) => params[1];
const test2 = fn2(['Bar', { bars: [0] }]);

// For example, try changing below to `Type extends (string & {}) | 'Foo'`. It will work.
//  (Or, add a readonly modifier to Foo.foos and Bar.bars.)
const fn3 = <Type extends string, const Item extends Type extends 'Foo' ? Foo : Bar>(params: { Type: Type, Item: Item }) => params.Item;
const test3 = fn3({
    Type: 'Foo',
    Item: {
      foos: ["huh"]
    }
  });

// This one actually works as is!
const fn4 = <Type extends string, const Item extends Type extends 'Foo' ? Foo : Bar>(params: [Type: Type, Item: Item]) => params[1];
const test4 = fn4(['Bar', { bars: [0] }]);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKAzBBnALij2ACcBLAOwHMBtAXQG4oB6FqAQwBMurqpSEbnEoAbEFAAWEQVAC2HANYQ8UYNKhwK1Kh1FQAxhzwqoAdy2L0AX0bpQkKACEOpZGkxQARq8JRKAK5yXjIMzGycPHwCQlwi4lIy0ArKqurQWuQ6lHqGxqYWpFa29uDQALIcYJBcADwAKgB87hhYtADSUFRQyiBw2FD19ET1HUw2dg4VVTUA6paucAGUdU3u9VAQAB7AECuqGwD8UJXVEKvNRJQQAG4ydugR8G7bHHJgohAANGqkEgaSDg0aLpbwQURwMxqRAAAwMIhIUAAkrs5JsdnsuKpTnMFqQlisGmV0bt9lAAOTwODkqDHKlQIguUiNGEAOmRwHM5FE%20kKilZj3YUAAFAB5Ug-bhcTgxYRiCRyOC8bDkGTQ2AIVm4OCqIHSpmsnykPCsgCU6HhlER2EoAEZ3ETHNtSViKVSaQAfClM8k-S2IlEQNHOzHYmbnR3QENkykIGl0hAM5yuRqNYVgVxvPyoQZlEZlH6BuREItQaym5DNDOkLOsot2f2c3Yke0oG224WtLC5yBEWPUr6eLBFohd7s4fBEWgAIkkAUk0-oQ7LnnLDwi9Uk5FUgLSGjwb2g064EDA6mnnD3GS8ACsIAZOUYTJwvHA7j9tgZT5zyJyAiZdTUAIPmgKgSFiTQBiBTRb3vYBBSwTdoD5RZlldXA3HbThqgSaRZGMcxwVEAVGxwSgACYHXqYlo1dftPW9VxfUMBFOVLWiwzOVYaIxGN3VpDVEEZFM02rLMp2o3se2%20DkgxLVF6ArJAq0zOQ8FoW1xlI5tgEotsKOFWhyR9H4cyNPxaAABnoMtFPXdhnnRN4QJ%20Mh-kBYEaDBCEoWAWFJKjXjXWFEgKC8gAyNByygL16LZDkuR5cxLAFCIRXFSUeBlQQ5QSRVlVVNw-MErV8E4FZk1IQ1fDNC1WLIgBmKieJdVRQr4P16vYoKDha0M3TjAT6WE5l01U7NpPzSBC1ReSgzLJSVJrNS61RBt6p0pr9IaztlwCvt3UHccRw8ccsG1CzZ3nRdl2sVdTXswYt1UERoA4B8Aj0BI%20V1VRtwAQjqq1ORtAAWZqnR64gyA6ljgdk4MoYCkl%20voobExG0TxokvNpJmuSEcUysoDEtSNK0jaVGAcH9NBwzjKY0zvF8KdrNsh70CAA)

The [test cases](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/55229/files#diff-33ead52cd233fab8209aafd286e23177d9d8d823ccae52beb62707a1b2c7d37f) for microsoft/TypeScript#55229 do not include constraints like the ones I have above. Therefore, I am not sure if I am misunderstanding the extent to which and conditions under which the PR applies, or if there is something else going on here.

Any insight is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that I could have any good answer without digging into the compiler code; presumably ms/TS#55229 was meant to handle the common cases and not the specific nested mapped type stuff you're doing here. But in order to get confirmation I'd probably need to file an issue in the TS github repo and I'm not particularly inclined to do so, at least right now.  Don't know if anyone else has any ideas here?